# Python text cleaning and matching

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-mining

I am trying to get a cleaned address from a bunch of addresses.

These are different addresses I have for Harvard University. What I want is to convert all these addresses to "Harvard University".

1) Division of Renal Medicine, Department of Medicine, Brigham and Women's Hospital, Harvard Medical School, Harvard Institutes of Medicine Suite 550, 4 Blackfan Circle, Boston, Massachusetts 02115, USA

​2) FAS Center for Systems Biology, Harvard University, Cambridge, Massachusetts 02138

​3) Department of Neurobiology, Howard Hughes Medical Institute, Harvard Medical School, Boston, Massachusetts, United States of America.

Just simple text matching doesn't work. So, I tried difflib.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

a = "Division of Renal Medicine, Department of Medicine, Brigham and Women's Hospital, Harvard Medical School, Harvard Institutes of Medicine Suite 550, 4 Blackfan Circle, Boston, Massachusetts 02115, USA"
b = "Harvard University"
print(similar(a, b))  # gives 0.11981566820276497
print(similar(a, "Toronto University"))  # gives 0.04608294930875576
```

But I think this approach won't give correct results for my data set. How can I set a threshold for the similarity? Can anyone recommend a better approach?

Comment: what is your logic? any string containing harvard, convert to "harvard university" ? or is it based on postal code? can you elaborate more on the addresses you want to "convert" to "harvard unviersity" ?

Comment: Lets say you have complete addresses and possibly zipcodes in it. You can just have a list of zipcodes for that area and based on the matching logic for that you can convert all this address. You can spare yourself a lot of efforts for doing it based on matching.

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar All these addresses don't have zipcode. So, that is not possible.

Comment: @SantoshGhimire In that case you probably need an algorithm where you first lookup for zipcodes to match if not that then as jdigital suggested use synonyms, the ones you most likely see in this addresses.

Comment: if i am not mistaken, in string a, there is a zipcode...

Comment: You can just check address that has strings like either  *Harvard Institute* or *Harvard University* or *Harvard School* and replace them with "Harvard University"?